# Remover espaços em branco que estão em baixo das div

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou tentando retirar os espaços entre as divs mas não estou conseguindo. Já tentei usando fonte-size: 0, display: inline-bock ,float.

```css
html{ 
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: calc(50vw - 10rem);
    margin: 1.5rem auto;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    padding: 1rem 2rem ;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------ */


/*
------------------------------
teste com display-flex
------------------------------
*/

.container{ 
    width: calc(100% - 5rem);
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    font-size: 0;
}

.rect{
    margin: 0.5rem;
    flex: auto;
    width: 250px; 
    vertical-align: top;
    border-radius: 1rem;
} 

img, video{
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FlexBox - Grow e Shrink</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="14 - FlexBox - Grow e Shrink Flex.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Grid responsivo de testes
    </h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="rect r1">
            <a href="img"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/d2/66/08/d26608c8e000b109fab3fcd84575e49e.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <div class="title-img"><h4>Titulo Imagem</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rect r2">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/61/9d/54/619d54a31dde1116d86d20b2bf4bd679.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="rect r3">
            <a href="video1"><img id="v1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e8/07/32/e80732efd31536e193852dfe96f7e59e.jpg"></img></a>
            <!-- <div class="title-video"><h4>Titulo Video</h4></div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="rect">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/73/c8/1f/73c81f7b1d9f1aec94d25a4aa8b2e857.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="rect">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/36/1a/3b/361a3b8d234956f1e8c3b831e9272411.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="rect">
            <img id="v2" loop controls  src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/ea/39/d7/ea39d7fc839dd4e67b87cc88cd00ff64.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="rect">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e4/76/1d/e4761df2d9290d00a909d56693026525.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="rect">
            <img id='v3' loop controls src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e5/02/7e/e5027e8699c0fed18fd30556cd0fe211.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="rect">
            <img loop controls src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/24/92/60/249260f39ffd0d40ba21c0a34de0ce08.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="rect">
            <img id="v4" loop controls src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a0/08/96/a00896535553678e793deae69307a2f4.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="rect">
            <img id="i1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/69/2f/41/692f414b6827f1d87ddb320e87777721.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/3d/a2/ed/3da2eda16216514aab723133e972428c.jpg" alt="img1" srcset=""></div>
        <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e2/cf/4e/e2cf4e5b1248416d8822e5b1520e74eb.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/69/f4/17/69f417f6c719717dded58d8524878fe5.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/d2/0b/36/d20b362a9cf422dd0e056bf32ddde12c.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/03/b2/bd/03b2bdd5acf67ab6fb4b60eb03ae6925.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/52/68/e9/5268e966d9221dc51a871c41e2b341fc.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

O problema está na margem que você está a dar a cada div, isso cria o espaço entre elas. Usei `display: grid` e retirei a margem. Era esse o resultado que você queria? Confira em baixo

```css
html {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: calc(50vw - 10rem);
  margin: 1.5rem auto;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}


/* ------------------------------------------------------ */


/*
------------------------------
teste com display-flex
------------------------------
*/

.container {
  width: calc(100% - 5rem);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-size: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.rect {
  width: 250px;
  height:200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

img,
video {
  width: 300px;
  height:300px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>FlexBox - Grow e Shrink</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="14 - FlexBox - Grow e Shrink Flex.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Grid responsivo de testes
  </h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="rect r1">
      <a href="img"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/d2/66/08/d26608c8e000b109fab3fcd84575e49e.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <div class="title-img">
        <h4>Titulo Imagem</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rect r2">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/61/9d/54/619d54a31dde1116d86d20b2bf4bd679.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="rect r3">
      <a href="video1"><img id="v1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e8/07/32/e80732efd31536e193852dfe96f7e59e.jpg"></img>
      </a>
      <!-- <div class="title-video"><h4>Titulo Video</h4></div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="rect">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/73/c8/1f/73c81f7b1d9f1aec94d25a4aa8b2e857.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="rect">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/36/1a/3b/361a3b8d234956f1e8c3b831e9272411.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="rect">
      <img id="v2" loop controls src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/ea/39/d7/ea39d7fc839dd4e67b87cc88cd00ff64.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="rect">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e4/76/1d/e4761df2d9290d00a909d56693026525.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="rect">
      <img id='v3' loop controls src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e5/02/7e/e5027e8699c0fed18fd30556cd0fe211.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="rect">
      <img loop controls src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/24/92/60/249260f39ffd0d40ba21c0a34de0ce08.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="rect">
      <img id="v4" loop controls src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a0/08/96/a00896535553678e793deae69307a2f4.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="rect">
      <img id="i1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/69/2f/41/692f414b6827f1d87ddb320e87777721.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/3d/a2/ed/3da2eda16216514aab723133e972428c.jpg" alt="img1" srcset=""></div>
    <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e2/cf/4e/e2cf4e5b1248416d8822e5b1520e74eb.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/69/f4/17/69f417f6c719717dded58d8524878fe5.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/d2/0b/36/d20b362a9cf422dd0e056bf32ddde12c.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/03/b2/bd/03b2bdd5acf67ab6fb4b60eb03ae6925.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="rect"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/52/68/e9/5268e966d9221dc51a871c41e2b341fc.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Na verdade eu queria essas divs posicionadas igual o feed do pinterest, sebe me dizer se tem como? se existe alguma biblioteca, framework para me ajudar nisso?